# Кэширование картинки в броузер

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

У меня есть к примеру на странице картинки 1.png - 22.png как мне их кэшировать в броузер, да бы пользователь когда зашел на сайт, не ждал прогрузки при наведении на них? наверно это js, но все, что было найдено в интернете, не работало, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я обычно по событию `window.ready` меняю `src` у картинок. Сами `img` в html должны быть без src (или, лучше, чтобы указывал на заглушку), а путь храню в `data-` параметрах.
Получается что-то вроде:

```
$('[data-postload]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', $this.data('postload'));
});
```

Если нужно подгрузить большие изображения, которые в будущем (возможно) затребует юзер, можно создавать объекты в памяти:

```
var images = ['path/1', 'path/2', 'path/n'];
$.each(images, function(index, value) {
    $('<img src="'+value+'">');
});
```

Браузер сделает запрос в фоне и кеширует эти изображения.